# check if the entered answer matches in array xml android

Tags: android, arrays

Im creating a quiz, i've a textview for Question, a textfield for answer, and a button to check if the answer is right or wrong. I have 2 xml file, one for question array and the other for the answer array.

```
public class ArrayAct extends Activity{
Button mButton;
EditText mEdit;
String [] mArray;
String [] mArray1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.arrayact);


    mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Answers);
    mArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questions);

    final Button doneBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
    final EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFld);

    doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Arrays.asList(mArray).contains(text.getText().toString()))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect.Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView); 
    Random random = new Random();

    int maxIndex = mArray1.length;
    int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);

    textView.setText(mArray1[generatedIndex]);   
}
```

}

What code should i implement so it would check if the entered answer matches the right answer to the question?

Comment: Use Question and answer as key value pairs like HashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class ArrayAct extends Activity {

    private Button doneBtn;
    private EditText text;
    private TextView textView;
    private String [] mArray;
    private String [] mArray1;
    private int generatedIndex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.arrayact);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        doneBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFld);

        mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Answers);
        mArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questions);

        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mArray[generatedIndex].equals(text.getText().toString()))
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect.Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        Random random = new Random();

        generatedIndex = random.nextInt(mArray1.length);
        textView.setText(mArray1[generatedIndex]);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, how would i set it to only display three questions? And if user entered an answer that isn't correct, it won't go to the next question..

Comment: please ask new question with your requirement send me link to this question then i'll try to help you there.

Comment: Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505585/limit-the-displayed-questions-from-array-android) @Haresh