# Limit the displayed questions from array android

Tags: android

I want to set my quiz to only show three questions , and not proceeding to the next one until it gets the correct answer. Here's my current code

My application goes like this by the way,

- Textview for Question
- Textfield for Answer
- Button to check if answer is correct/incorrect

  ```
  public class ArrayAct extends Activity {

  private Button doneBtn;
  private EditText text;
  private TextView textView;
  private String [] mArray;
  private String [] mArray1;
  private int generatedIndex;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.arrayact);

      textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
      doneBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
      text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFld);

      mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Answers);
      mArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questions);

      doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              if (mArray[generatedIndex].equals(text.getText().toString()))
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              else
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect.Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      });

      Random random = new Random();

      generatedIndex = random.nextInt(mArray1.length);
      textView.setText(mArray1[generatedIndex]);
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: is your question array size grater than three or same ?

Comment: Both arrays contain 5 items. I just want to show only 3 everytime a user takes the quiz

Comment: okay one more question is same question repeated becz using random no ?

Comment: Questions should not be repeated for the given three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class ArrayAct extends Activity {
    private Button doneBtn;
    private EditText text;
    private TextView textView;
    private String [] mArray;
    private String [] mArray1;
    private int generatedIndex;
    private HashMap<String,String> questionMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.arrayact);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        doneBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBtn);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFld);

        mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Answers);
        mArray1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Questions);
        questionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(doneBtn.getText().equals("Close")){
                    finish();
                }else{
                    if (mArray[generatedIndex].equals(text.getText().toString())){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(questionMap.size()==3){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your test is over!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            doneBtn.setText("Close");
                        }else{
                            text.setText("");
                            prepareQuestion();
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect.Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        prepareQuestion();
    }

    private void prepareQuestion(){
        Random random = new Random();
        do{
            generatedIndex = random.nextInt(mArray1.length);
        }while(questionMap.containsKey(String.valueOf(generatedIndex)));
        questionMap.put(String.valueOf(generatedIndex),"");
        textView.setText(mArray1[generatedIndex]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mArray[generatedIndex].equals(text.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(arrayOfUsedIndexes.size() == 3) {
                //Some reaction for all 3 questions answered correctly
            }
            else {
               int newGeneratedIndex;
               do {
                  newGeneratedIndex = random.nextInt(mArray1.length);
               } while(arrayOfUsedIndexes.contains(newGeneratedIndex))
               textView.setText(mArray1[newGeneratedIndex]);
               arrayOfUsedIndexes.add(newGeneratedIndex);
           }
       } 
       else {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect.Please try again.",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
  }
});

Random random = new Random();

generatedIndex = random.nextInt(mArray1.length);
arrayOfUsedIndexes.add(generatedIndex);
textView.setText(mArray1[generatedIndex]);
```